# How to add more targets in chrome inspect tab

Tags: node.js, debugging, backend, chrome-debugging

Im trying to debug the backend repo and i want to use the chrome's debugger. i got to see a video in youtube where i got to know about the --inspect flag while starting the repo i.e.:

```
node --inspect index.js
```

Im able to attach break points in this repo and the debugger is working fine.

Now the problem is from this backend repo im making request to one more backend repo that i have started in different port like below

```
node --inspect=127.0.0.1:9233 index.js
```

But im not able to see target in chrome inspect tab

```
chrome://inspect/#devices
```

im only able to see the first repo on the port 9229 like below
[image]

So as you can see the above picture there is only the option to inspect only the first backend repo but i want to get the other two repos as well.
Currently even after attaching the breakpoints in all the three backend repos its working(stopping at the breakpoints) only for the first repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there!

1. Open `chrome://inspect` page
2. Press the button `Configure` and add the debugger's host and port in the displayed window

[image: target discovery window]

Comment: I think this might work but i found another way also look below

Comment: Posted my answer...

Answer (score 0):

Found a way to add new target to inspect

1. Open chrome://inspect page
2. click on `Open dedicated DevTools for Node`
   [image]
3. click on `connection tab`
4. click on `Add connection` and Just add the new port number.
5. click add button and your done.
   [image]